# How to cleanly convert hardrive with existing windows installation to external harddrive for storage?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I recently replaced my laptop with one that has an absurdly tiny hard drive.  However, I still have my old laptop, which is no longer functional but does have a functional HD.  Thus I decided to remove my old laptops HD and make it an external one to supplement my new laptops tiny internal HD.

My problem is that my old HD has a full windows installation and a bunch of other duplicate software on it that is no longer needed, along with allot of things I do want to lose.  I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to remove all the software that I want installed on my internal HD, including the windows installation, from my external HD without wiping all the things I still wish to retain.

Do I need to boot up off of the old HD to easily remove software, or is there a tool that will assist me with doing that without changing my boot config?  While this is less important is there a way to remove the windows I don't think I need but still keep the license in case I want to reinstall that windows installation somewhere one day?

Comment: Buy a 3TB HDD (they are cheap now maybe £10 used). Now mount the old HDD to your existing windows system and drag drop the important files to back them up. When finished, wipe the old HDD and start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

I believe DriveZilla will be able to fix your issue.
If not, BalenaEtcher allows to copy drives, source to target, but [there has been reports of malfunctions erasing both drives.](https://forums.balena.io/t/balena-etcher-clone-drive-now-have-two-blank-drives/213065)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).